# Мониторинг редко используемых, но важных функций

Tags: zabbix, мониторинг, grafana

Всем привет! Имеется ряд важных функций, которых необходимо замониторить через графану, однако, так как приложение не слишком востребовано у пользователей, успешных и неуспешных (в контексте) событий не так много. Мониторинг пока настроил базово: на 10% неуспешных ответов за 15 минут от количества успешных+неуспешных ответов. Интервал сбора данных - каждые 5 минут.
Проблема следующая: на основании того, что приложение не популярно и им пользуется небольшое кол-во пользователей - при натыкании пользователя на ошибку сразу же стреляет триггер, так как (предположим), 1 ошибка от 2х ответов = 50%.
Сразу оговорюсь, что поднять порог триггера не представляется возможным, так как есть регламент.
Так вот, может кто-то знает какую-нибудь универсальную "удачную" функцию или формулу для адекватного условия под триггеры для важных, но не всотребованных функций?